# Leer archivos de texto de un servidor

Tags: python

Tengo un pequeño programa que lee un archivo de texto en el mismo directorio en el que tengo mi programa de python e imprime el número de líneas que tiene:

```
fichero = open('archivo1.txt', 'r')
print (len(fichero.readlines())) 
fichero.close()
```

Sin embargo, tengo que leer varios archivos que están ubicados en un servidor externo, ubicados en una ruta.
Ruta de ejemplo: https://datos.empresa.es/anios/mes/dia
De forma que si tengo que acceder a un archivo ubicado, por ejemplo, en el día 1 de un mes cualquiera pues tendría esta ruta: https://datos.empresa.es/anios/mes/01/archivo.txt

Sin embargo no sé cómo puedo leer un archivo en cuestión. Pensé que bastaba con poner:

```
    fichero = open('https://datos.empresa.es/anios/mes/01/archivo.txt', 'r')
    print (len(fichero.readlines())) 
    fichero.close()
```

Pero no me funciona.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Para lo que quieres puedes usar la librería `requests`: [Requests: HTTP para Humanos](https://requests.readthedocs.io/es/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado esta forma de hacerlo que creo te puede servir:

```
import urllib.request

URL = "https://datos.empresa.es/anios/mes/01/archivo.txt"
file = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)

lines = []
for line in file:
    decoded_line = line.decode("utf-8")
    lines.append(decoded_line)

print(len(lines))
```

Se usa la librería `urllib` ya que con `open()` no se pueden realizar peticiones HTTP.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte! Pero no sé por qué cuando utilizo este método me devuelve una línea de más. Si utilizo el código de la otra respuesta obtengo en un fichero que tiene 178 líneas (que es lo correcto) en cambio con este obtengo 179. ¿Sabes a qué se puede deber? Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar algo como esto:

```
import requests
r = requests.get("https://datos.empresa.es/anios/mes/01/archivo.txt")
content = r.text

lines = content.split('\n')
print(len(lines))
```

Con el método de `split()` de una cadena obtienes fácilmente las líneas del archivo y luego con `len()` las cuentas.

Usando Http no puedes listar los archivos de un directorio. Lo más que puedes hacer es obtener los links que existen en paginas como index.html e interpretarlos como directorios. Para ello te recomiendo el modulo [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Pruebalo y comprueba si se adapta a tu pagina.

Pero si conoces como se estructura la pagina web, puedes usar eso a tu favor y hacer un script como este:

```
import requests
url = "https://datos.empresa.es/anios/mes/"
url_i = [];
content = [];

for i in range(1,29):
    if i<10:
        url_i.append(url+"0"+str(i)+"/archivo.txt")
    else:
        url_i.append(url+str(i)+"/archivo.txt")
    #print (url_i[i-1])  # Muestra las urls creadas


for n in range(len(url_i)):
    r = requests.get(url_i[n])
    content.append(r.text) 
    lines = content[n].split('\n')
    print(len(lines))
```

La lista url_i guardara la url los 28 dias del mes de febrero y content será una lista con el contenido de "archivo.txt" de cada dia del mes.

Comment: Perfecto, me sirve genial. Solo otra duda más. En la dirección de mes tengo diferentes carpetas con los días (por ejemplo, si es febrero tengo 28 carpetas, una por día), y dentro de cada carpeta tengo varios archivos. ¿Cómo puedo aplicar este proceso para leer todos los archivos de cada carpeta? Porque al estar trabajando con archivos en una url estoy perdido :/

Comment: Actualice mi respuesta para intentar responder tu comentario. :)

Comment: Muy amable, gracias por tu aporte! Ahora tengo que salir, pero en cuanto pueda le echo un vistazo y te comento^^

Comment: Comento mi problema. He tomado una ruta en concreto de un archivo en URL. Almaceno los valores de ese txt en una lista A y a su vez creo otra lista B en la que guardo solo los valores que me interesan analizar de A. Eso lo he hecho para un archivo en concreto pero cómo puedo hacer que en lugar de poner una ruta fija para leer un archivo fijo me vaya haciendo eso con todos los archivos que hay en el mes? Porque yo lo hice solo para un archivo del día 1, pero quisiera hacerlo para el resto de archivos del día 1 y del resto de días, no obstante con el código que me compartiste no me sale